# Connfigure some urls to use 2-way SSL while others use 1-way SSL on Weblgic Application server

Tags: java, spring, ssl, weblogic, tls1.2

I have three spring applications running on weblogic 12.2.1.4.0.
Two of these applications (App1 and App2) expose REST APIs which they use for intercommunication.
Some of these REST endpoints are also called by the third application(App3) which is bundled with Angular.

Scenario:

1. user opens browser and types in xyx.com (requesting a page from App3)
2. App3 receives the request and then makes a back end call to either App1 or App2.
3. App1/App2 returns a response to to App3
4. App3 forwards the response to the browser.

Problem:
When 2-way SSL is configured, App3 can communicate with App1/App2 correctly. However, before we ever get to this part, the client must initiate the request from the frontend(browser). But because 2-way SSL is enabled, it fails when the browser initiates the request. This is becasue the certificate trusted by the server is not install on the browser.

Question:
Is is possible to configure weblogic such that:

1. Communication between the browser and App3 uses 1 way ssl
2. Communication between App3 and App1/App2 uses 2 way ssl.

NOTE Assume that App3 is deployed on a seperate server

I have tried to configure a different http listener for the requests which come from the browser, but I con't see how to do this isn weblogic server 12.2.1.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: [enable mTLS in Weblogic](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/security/ConfigureTwowaySSL.html) with the option "**Client Certs Requested But Not Enforced**". This enables optional 2-way TLS while still allowing  browsers to connect to App3 with 1-way SSL.
- Step 2: change App3 to provide a client certificate when connecting to App1/App2.
- Step 3: change App1/App2 to verify if the connection included a valid client certificate.

Note that it's not possible to *require* client certificates based on URL/path, because the certificate must be presented during the TLS handshake, before the path is sent. Luckily your problem can be solved with *"client certs requested but not enforced"*, since you control the client that wants to use mTLS.